# How can I select particular number of character words with regex

Tags: regex, text

I have a text like below.

```
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum 
has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the fivec harword 1500s, when an unknown printer 
took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen fivec harword book. It has survived not
only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of fivec harword Letraset sheets containing 
Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus 
PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Here's what I need with regex:

1- select five char word.

2- select a space after first step.

3- select seven char word after second step.

It should capture all `fivec harword` strings. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this one:

```
\b\w{5}\s\w{7}\b
```

**explanation:**

```
The regular expression:

(?-imsx:\b\w{5}\s\w{7}\b)

matches as follows:

NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w{5}                    word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (5
                           times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \w{7}                    word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (7
                           times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \b                       the boundary between a word char (\w) and
                           something that is not a word char
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick

```
(^|\W)\w{5}\s\w{7}($|\W)
```

`(^|\W)` start of the string or a non-word character.

`\w{5}` a string of 5 word characters

`\s` a space

`\w{7}` a string of 7 word characters

`($|\W)` end of the string or a non-word character

If you specifically want spaces around the string (as opposed to punctuation etc) replace both `\W` with `\s`

Comment: This will not match at the begining or at the end of the string.

Comment: Why this one doesn't works? I added 5 char word end of regex. `\W\w{5}\s\w{7}\s\w{5}\W` I tried with proper text that should find.

Comment: M42 was right, I've adjusted mine to cater for start and end of string (still allowing the flexibility to match spaces if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
\b[a-zA-Z]{5}\s[][a-zA-Z]{7}\b
```

\b indicates boundary

[a-zA-Z] all alpha bets

{5} 5 characters with previous expression

\s single white space